# Declaring variables in Sybase ASE 15.7

Tags: variables, sybase

Sybase documentation says to declare variables using:

```
declare @a int
declare @b char(20)
declare @c float
```

However, when I do it I get the following error:

```
declare @a int
Error report -
Invalid JDBC escape syntax at line position 17 '=' character expected.
```

I have NO idea why lol. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you call the code? with `executeStatement()`? Can you paste the whole code sample?

Comment: @AdamLeszczyński the code example is simply the second block in the original post `declare @a int`. To run the code there is a run button in the Oracle SQL Developer IDE that im using.

Comment: @ShiZhang: you're saying that the only command you're trying to execute is `declare @a int` and it's generating an error?  I'd suggest you try submitting your problematic code via the `isql` command line tool ... and if you get no errors then there's a problem with the client/front-end application you're using (Oracle SQL Developer in this case?); in other words, if `isql` doesn't report any errors then this isn't a Sybase ASE problem but rather a problem with the tool you're using to access Sybase ASE